Particles not showing
I have a small animation that uses particles, in my case I want the part of the animation that is between 540-700 frames. I can render it normally and it comes out fine with the particles and all, but I do want to slow down their movement. The speed control doesn't give exactly what I want, but using time stretching I do get the results I want.
But when I try to render (after finding the new frames for the same animation), the particles won't show up anymore. I have to render all the way from frame 0 for particles to show up in frame 1200. Is there a work around?

This is expected behavior. Blender has to build the cache from the starting frame of the simulation: It cannot begin time in the middle of history as it were. What you can do in the particle settings is bake the cache (which will lock the settings until/unless you clear the bake), and that will pre-calculate all particle frames and save the cache to disk, so you can play from any position.

Does that mean I'd have to bake all the way from frame zero or just the range I'd want?

@SilverSaber You have to bake from the start of the cache. You can move the start up, but it will still be the start, not some intermediate point. Blender can’t accurately create particles in the middle of their lifespan.
